# Converting TableView to PDF - Issue: final PDF image overlaps when creating new pages

Tags: swift, tableview, pdfkit

I am converting my TableView to a PDF like so:

```
func pdfDataWithTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Data? {
    
     let priorBounds = tableView.bounds
     
     let fittedSize = tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(
     width: priorBounds.size.width,
     height: tableView.contentSize.height
     ))
     
     tableView.bounds = CGRect(
     x: 0, y: 0,
     width: fittedSize.width,
     height: fittedSize.height
     )
     
     let pdfPageBounds = CGRect(
     x :0, y: 0,
     width: tableView.frame.width,
     height: self.view.frame.height
     )
     
     let pdfData = NSMutableData()
     UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil)
     
     var pageOriginY: CGFloat = 0
     while pageOriginY < fittedSize.height {
     UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.saveGState()
     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.translateBy(x: 0, y: -pageOriginY)
     tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.restoreGState()
     pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height
     tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: pageOriginY) // move "renderer"
     }
     UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
     
     tableView.bounds = priorBounds
     var docURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
     docURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("myDocument.pdf")
     pdfData.write(to: docURL as URL, atomically: true)
     
     return pdfData as Data
}
```

The code is working great; I can convert multiple different sized cells to a pdf displayed on multiple pages.

Now the issue is because it is just an image the PDF displays cut off when new page is shown... Example below:

[image]

I am looking for a solution to avoid this... Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please specify which kind of solution you are looking for, it's unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: @ArtemGarmash Sorry I thought I was clear, Basically I want the cells not to be overlapped when going to page 2 of the pdf document. So if it will not fit on page one move to page two.